# Connecting to Heroku Postgres Database from Outside of Heroku App with JDBC

Tags: heroku, jdbc, heroku-postgres, wolfram-language

I'm trying to connect to a free tier Heroku database from the Wolfram Language. The DatabaseLink package uses JDBC to make the connection. When I specify that SSL should be used for the connection, I get:

JDBC: SSL error: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

The support article at:
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/DatabaseLink/tutorial/SecureSocketLayer.html

... seems to suggest that one needs to get the security certificate for the site, generate a "truststore" file, and then load the JVM in a way that specifies which truststore file should be used.

I'm unsure if this is leading me in the right direction or not. But as of now, I'm unsure how I would go about getting this security certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have stumbled upon at least one way to get around the failure I was seeing, as described in the "Using SSL without Certificate Validation" section of:

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ssl-client.html

I was able to specify the `sslfactory` option via:

```
OpenSQLConnection[
    ...,
    "Properties" -> {"ssl" -> "true", "sslfactory" -> "org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory"}
]
```

Now the database connection is succeeding.